# Should an API contain front datas?

Tags: php, api, crud

Our tech team works on one website which is the main product of our company.
We have a back office website used to help everyone work on the product efficiently.

We'd like to make the website better and create a middle earth between the back office and the front product since they share the same datas.
We also want to create a mobile application that'll share (again) the same datas.

We thought about making an API containing all of the business model.

Now what's the most consistent and effective use to this ?
Should the API contain only CRUD models ? Then the logic isn't shared across domains...
Should it contain every back end logic possible ? Wouldn't that be dead code on one side or another one ?

Should it contain front end code ? I mean generated HTML templates that it'll fill with data itself ?
The problem I got with this last question is this :
Page A.
Need model X to display basic properties. API sends it. 
Need to use method 1 on X to display some data. I can't because I don't have access to X methods now.

Answer (score 0):

An API should deliver the data you need to work with. Also, it should contain all business logic, except things like sorting or something like this.

So you have an webpage as example, that works with your data. The complete layout, design whatsoever is within the webpages project. All the data you need will be required through the API though.

Of course, if you need the same data quite often, you may think about caching such results. That could be done provider-wise (API) or consumer-wise (example webpage).

The point of working with the data is, that your consumer just gathers the information it needs to send an request to the provider (API) and gets the information delivered, so that the consumer just needs to show them or decide what to do next.

All heavy work lays down on the API site, else the API wouldn't make any sense, since the goal is to provide one single point, that contains all your logic. [You shouldn't repeat yourself.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don't_repeat_yourself)